# typescript defining generic type for callback function

Tags: typescript, antd

I am using the following function to validate fields using the ant design framework:

```
this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values: any) => {
      if (!err) {
        this.setState(
          {
            ...values
          }
        );
      } else {
        console.log('ERROR!');
      }
    });
  };
```

Instead of 'any' I want to specify the type of the values being returned in the callback because I know what the input fields are that will be validated:

```
interface fieldProps {
firstName: string;
lastName:string;
}
```

In the ant design type defs I can see the following:

```
validateFieldsAndScroll(callback: ValidateCallback<V>): void;
```

and the type definition for validateCallback:

```
export declare type ValidateCallback<V> = (errors: unknown, values: V) => void;
```

my question is, how do I overload the V generic type to so that in my validate function I can specify the type for the fields value being returned in the callback to be of type fieldProps ?

Comment: Isn't it simply `validateFieldsAndScroll<fieldProps>(...) `?

Comment: I don't know this framework at all, but what is the type of `this.props.form`? Because the `ValidateCallback<V>` generic type actually comes from `WrappedFormUtils<V>`. [See here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/8ae479d91667ea696478f955f792c7368d9533e7/components/form/Form.tsx#L138-L165)